# Cross Domain Tracking with Universal Analytics and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I'm tracking everything through Google Tag Manager.

So I have my main domain `example.com` and I have a landing page at my parter's domain `landingpage.partner.com`. This landing page is redirected to `partner.example.com` with a DNS CNAME redirect.

Without any customization the traffic from the `landingpage.partner.com` will be tracked as a referrer in Google Analytics.

What I want to do is to track the traffic from `landingpage.partner.com` as my own traffic. So I have setup the GTM according to the [UA dev guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink) with the "autolink" features. I have tried to add both `landingpage.partner.com` and `partner.com` in the "Auto Links Domain" field. The traffic is still getting tracked as referred traffic.

How should I set this up in GTM, in order to track my traffic as my own and not as referred traffic?

[image: GTM Screenshot]

Comment: Is linked allowed on your partner's landing page?

Comment: @PetrHavlík Yes it's allowed. I use the same container on both my partners landing page and on my own site, but running different tags on them.

Comment: Simon, any chance you can provide real links?

Comment: Did you remember to add partner.com to the referral exclusion list ?

Comment: I know this is bogus data, but to be sure: did you add partner.com to the comma-separated list of domains in the Auto Link Domains field?